# Get all the ids which do not have transactions in last 6 months

Tags: sql

I have a table with three columns

```
ID   DATE   desc
```

I want to get the ids in a month that have not made transactions in the last 6 months based on the date column.

For instance : an id 123 qualifies for month jan 2018 if it is not having any data in the last 6 months. we need to do this for a span of 2 years from say june 2016 to june 2018.

I need help with a SQL query for this.

Comment: This is not a code writing service but a place where you get help with specific coding questions.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: are working working with sql server

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

considering your question this could be valid solution

```
SELECT * INPUT_TABLE IT1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (select DATEPART(month, DATE) AS month ,* from INPUT_TABLE IT2 WHERE 
        DATEPART(month, IT2.DATE) BETWEEN 
     DATEPART(month, IT1.DATE)- 5 and  DATEPART(month, IT1.DATE))
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: sql server is useed